# JSON file is empty, but a value is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to save a input into my database and showing it in my JSON file so I can output it on my website. When I type in a name in the input and then click on the save action everything is alright. No errors, and when I check the rails console I get,

```
from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):002:0> Movie.last
  Movie Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies"  ORDER BY "movies"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Movie id: 5, created_at: "2015-08-24 06:37:46", updated_at: "2015-08-24 06:37:46", user_id: nil, image: nil, title: "Star Wars", release_date: nil>
```

The only data I'm currently saving is the title.

But when I visit `http://localhost:3000/movies.json` The output is,

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

There are 7 id's in the database and when I add another one the json output gives 8 times null.

So why isn't my input being shown in the JSON output?

Routes.rb

```
resources :movies, only: [:create, :index, :show]
```

movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_with Movie.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with Movie.create(movie_params)
  end

  private
  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following. I hope this will help you out.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @movies }
    end
  end

  def create
    respond_with Movie.create(movie_params)
  end

  private
  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've tried it, but still the output is null null null.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to be `respond_to` at top

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def index
    respond_with Movie.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with Movie.create(movie_params)
  end

  private
  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title)
  end

end
```

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3

Comment: I've declared `respond_to :html, :json` in my `application_controller.rb`. That includes the `respond_to` to every controller right?